# Code working with xib, but not with Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, exc-bad-access

I am newbie for iPhone application. I am learning how to get the JSON data and parse it and show it in table in iPhone. For that I am going through [**`this video`**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k).

I made this with xib file and its working perfectly.

What I was trying is do this with `Storyboard`. I did same thing as I did for `Stoaryboard`, however the execution is getting break at below line.

`cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];`

Code I have is

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"i m here 1");

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    NSLog(@"i m here 2");

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
        NSLog(@"i m here 3");
    }
    NSLog(@"i m here 4");
    cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    // cell.textLabel.text = @"dadsf ad";
    NSLog(@"i m here 5");
    return cell;
}
```

In `NSLog`, I get output till `i m here 4`.

When I comment `cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex` and uncomment `cell.textLabel.text = @"dadsf ad";`, it works and I see `dadsf ad` in iPhone.

```
// cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.textLabel.text = @"dadsf ad";
```

When I run with `cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAt`, I get below screen.

[image]

### Note:

I also went to simulator and did `Reset Content and Setting`, still facing same problem. Any idea why?

---

### Update 1

I activate the `NSZombieEnabled` and run the code. I get in NSLOG as

```
JSONNewsStoryBoard[19389:11303] i m here 4
2013-01-06 11:26:15.327 JSONNewsStoryBoard[19389:11303] *** -[CFArray objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7497040
```

Below is the screen shot.

[image]

---

### Update 2 - ANSWER

I tried adding `NSLog(@"checking news count %d", [news count]);` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I got same problem. Means `news` was null.

So I added

```
news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it worked. :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `news` object has been deallocated sometime before `objectAtIndex:` is called on it, and this probably has something to do with the way interface builder and storyboard take over control of the objects you give them.  Try checking if `news` is equal to `nil` at various points in your code.  You may have to instantiate `news` at a different point in time.

Comment: you got it right... when I add `NSLog(@"checking news count %d", [news count]);` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I get same error. So I added `news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I am done.